# WAR not deploy on Jetty Server

Tags: java, jetty

I need deply WAR on Jetty server, but war can't deployed, what is my mistake?

```
public class JettyJmxServer {
private static final int SERVER_PORT = 8080;
private static final String PATH_TO_WAR = "src/main/webapp/";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Server server = new Server(SERVER_PORT);
        WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();

        root.setWar(PATH_TO_WAR);

        root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        server.setHandler(root);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
}
```

I see WAR on localhost:8080, but when i address to localhost:8080/jolokia-war-1.5.0 nothing found.

When I use ready Jetty Server, and place WAR to folder 'webapps' everything works perfectly.

Comment: check you server log! you will get idea

Comment: what happens when you set PATH_TO_WAR to full path to your war file. it seems it needs a url to a file http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.4.3.v20170317/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#setWar-java.lang.String-

Comment: I use setWar() and set full path to war and it's work. This solve my problem. But if i want dynamic generate WAR files, i need alway hardcode path to war, it's not best practices :(